# how to use svm-scale in LIBSVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I tried running the command `svm-scale -l 0 -u 1 -s range data.data > data_scaled.data` but I get the error: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax.` Please find details in the picture below.

[image: cmd]

I am running the command in a Windows command shell using a Python interface. Is my command format wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I assume, that you use the original LIBSVM (as mentioned in the title of your question) package from [here](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/).

There the call should be `svm-scale -l 0 -u 1 -s scaledParameters.txt input.data`

According to the code, it will print the scaled output to your terminal. The `-s` option will write down the ranges of your feature values, e.g.

```
x
0 1
1 63375 13454352
2 1 10
3 1 10
4 1 10
5 1 10
6 1 10
7 1 10
8 1 10
9 1 10
10 1 10
```

If you just want to scale your data, you have to adapt the LIBSVM scale code to write the scaled data into a file.